# Ajustar HTML en columnas

Tags: html, css

La idea es poder ajustar un HTML de un iFrame para que se muestre en 2 o 3 columnas, tal como haríamos en Word para que el texto nos quede en columnas.

Entiendo que debería haber una forma en CSS de hacerlo, y he visto algunas ideas con  pero no me ha funcionado.

Quiero colocar dos iFrame en una página, con el contenido en columnas, como si fuera nota de periódico. Y poder imprimir en una hoja.

Esto pero con html
https://ordenadorpractico.es/pluginfile.php/375/mod_page/content/3/texto-colmnas.jpg

Comment: Podrías compatir, lo que haz hecho y así ver si estás cerca de la solución o no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar una propiedad de css, deberás colocar un `<p>` dentro de un `<div>` y éste podrá dividirse.

```
<div class="cols">
    <p>Texto muy largo</p>
</div>

<style>
    .cols {
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Gracias Jonathan, eso es lo que necesito!

Comment: @LuisHernández ¿Esta respuesta solucionó tu problema? Por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada si tu problema fue resuelto. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!